# How to make eve create DOMAIN endpoints programmatically

Tags: python, flask, eve

I am trying to make Python Eve create different collections programmatically,

Let's say I want to expose an endpoint receiving a schema to be able to create that collection in mongo:

i.e

```
DOMAIN = {}

app.route('/gen')
def gen(schema):
    app.config['DOMAIN'][schema.name] = schema.def # <-- This obviously does not work, don't know how to focus it
```

So that via curl I could post this schema def:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"name":"test", "def": "{\"age\":\"int\"}"}]' http://localhost:5000/gen
```

And POST objects of this new collection(test) created

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"age":5]' http://localhost:5000/test
```

Obviously this is just the initial problem. In order to persist it in the future I will need to save this data in mongo, and load it once application starts, so that "mongo autodefines python eve DOMAIN itself". I hope this will also be possible to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is to use custom settings for `Eve()` object:

`app = eve.Eve(settings=settings)`

where `settings` contains `DOMAIN` definition:

```
settings = {
    "SERVER_NAME": None,
    "DEBUG": True,

    # MongoDB params
    "MONGO_HOST": '...',
    "MONGO_PORT": 27017,
    "MONGO_USERNAME": '...',
    "MONGO_PASSWORD": '...',

    .....

    # add to DOMAIN all collections defined in `schema`
    "DOMAIN": {
        # doc
        'app_doc': {
            'item_title': 'app_doc',
            'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
            'allow_unknown': True,
            'schema': {
                'name': {'type': 'string', 'required': True},
    ....
}
```

The settings variable could be modified in order to receive parameters from database (I use a collection named `app_schema` where I keep these custom definitions for endpoints).

Just connect to Mongo (I use pymongo) before instantiation of `Eve()`, then fill `settings["DOMAIN"]` with all data from `app_schema` collection, then pass this settings variable to `Eve(settings=settings)`. Exemple here:

```
# setup Mongo connection (@see config.py - store here default schemas and DOMAIN)
client = MongoClient(settings["MONGO_HOST"], settings["MONGO_PORT"])
db = client.docfill

# check app_schema collection
tab_schemas = db.app_schema.find({})


def load_settings_from_schema_collection():
    """
    Defines a new settings DOMAIN variable loaded with metadata regarding "ent_"-collections
        create other API endpoints by definitions found in schema
        this is a huge workload, as it analyzes each schemadef and create endpoints for various operations
        like GET/POST/DEL/PUT/PATCH and search
        :return:
    """
    i = 0

    # add to `settings` new definitions from app_schema collection
    global settings

    # now parse each doc and create settings table for it, the insert settings table into DOMAIN definition
    for doc in tab_schemas:
        i = i + 1
        # this name should be unique for each collection
        this_collection_name = "ent_" + doc["collection"]
        # only allow "ent_" prefixed schemas to be overridden
        this_schema_setting = {
            "datasource": {
                "source": this_collection_name  # important ca tabela sa fie definita cu prefix
            },
            "resource_methods": ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
            "item_methods": ['GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'PATCH'],
            "schema": {}
        }

        for fld_meta in doc["content"]:
            this_schema_setting["schema"][fld_meta] = {"type": doc["content"][fld_meta]["type"]}

            # is there a required option ?
            if "required" in doc["content"][fld_meta]:
                this_schema_setting["schema"][fld_meta] = {"required": bool(doc["content"][fld_meta]["required"])}

        settings["DOMAIN"][this_collection_name] = this_schema_setting

        # output everything in settings variable to config.js (just for viewing what happens in settings)
        file = "config.js"
        with open(file, 'w') as filetowrite:
            filetowrite.write('settings = ' + json.dumps(settings, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

    return 1


# load settings from schema collections in MongoDB: collection=app_schema
load_settings_from_schema_collection()
```

And finally, start server:

```
app = eve.Eve(settings=settings)

app.run(...)
```

Hope it helps!